# How do I read from AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider of a IConfiguration object?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

Hovering over an object of type IConfiguration in my Startup.cs 
I notice it has 6 providers:

```
{Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ChainedConfigurationProvider}
{JsonConfigurationProvider for 'appsettings.json' (Optional)}
{JsonConfigurationProvider for 'appsettings.Development.json' (Optional)} 
{EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider}
{CommandLineConfigurationProvider}
```

and most importantly for me

```
{AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider}
```

I know that I can read from appsettings.json by :

```
var x = configuration.GetSection("SectionA").GetSection("AKey").Value
```

but how can I read from the last provider: `{AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider}`, what is the syntax for this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. You read from the configuration as a whole. It layers the settings on top of each other. Keys in providers added earlier are overwritten by those with the same name added in later providers

Comment: AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider info definitely should override info from appsettings.json. I never explicitly add appsettings.json as a provider though, so how do i know if AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider will take priority? Just because it's the last one in the array quoted above?

Comment: Assuming you're using GenericHost or WebHost they get added by default first. You can clear the providers in ConfigureAppConfiguration... But any that you add manually get added after the default ones

Comment: Ok, that was very unexpected. Thank you so much.

Comment: By default it adds appsettings.json, appsettings.Environment.json, Environment variables, command line arguments and for Development builds it adds user secrets FYI

Comment: I was preparing to write some statements to switch to azure secrets if the elements were not defined in the local secrets or in appsettings ... also turns out if I want to read from local I just uncomment the `builder.AddAzureKeyVault` part from Program.cs... interesting...

Comment: "for Development builds it adds user secrets " - how does it know it's Development purposes?

Comment: It looks for Development environment name

Comment: I've seen IWebHostEnvironment env in Startup.cs as a param, and then if (env.IsDevelopment()) .. but where is this set?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/96a3bfed4acffbe88403d5f599cee358b880ac5d/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Host.cs#L80

Comment: In launchsettings.json something like this, I notice:` "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      } `

Comment: It's based on the environment name which defaults to production unless passed in via command line argument/environment variable **or** because you are running in visual studio and your launchsettings.json file specified AspNetCore_Environment (or in later versions, DotNet_Environment) environment variables which typically set default to Develolment

Comment: Yup. That's setting it to development